# context not timing out

Tags: http, go, settimeout

Im trying to use the context with timeout to exit a long running http GET request. The request to the url should take over 10 seconds but my request does not timeout after 2 seconds. What is the problem? the ctx that is passed to the makeGet() function is from the http handlefun r.Contex().

```
  makeGet(ctx context.Context, url string, respBuffer *bytes.Buffer) (int, error){
        req, err := http.NewRequest(http.MethodGet, url, nil)

            if err != nil {

                return 0, err
            }
            //
            ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(ctx, time.Second*2)
            defer cancel()

            req.WithContext(ctx)
            req.Header.Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
            client := &http.Client{}
            resp, err := client.Do(req)

            if err != nil {

                return 0, err
            }
    defer resp.Body.Close()
    _, err = respBuffer.ReadFrom(resp.Body)
    if err != nil {
        return resp.StatusCode, err
    }

    }
```

Comment: req =  req.WithContext(ctx), WithContext return a copy object after setting Context.

Comment: Or just pass it directly `Client.Do(req.WithContext(ctx))` to avoid any confusion.

Comment: Or use [NewRequestWithContext](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#NewRequestWithContext)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Summarizing answers in the comments from:

The issue with original code: `req.WithContext(ctx)` does not set context on request but, it returns a new request which has context set on it.

The issue can be fixed using new request to perform query using `req = req.WithContext(ctx)` or, using the return value directly in `Client.Do` which would be `Client.Do(req.WithContext(ctx))`